# Using Airflow, How to handle asynchronous API calls with Airflow Tasks?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver, airflow-api, airflow-taskflow

I'm quite new to Airflow, I need to make asynchronous POST API calls to start the execution of the external service. And Need to make GET API calls to check the status of the execution and have to make that call until the execution gets completed.

I have tried having one task to make a POST API call and Another task to keep on calling the GET API until it's completed, The problem with this approach is, My execution may even take an hour to get completed. I dont want to make my task been active until gets the completed status from GET call.

I would like to know, What is the best way to achieve these goals in Airflow? Are there any specific operators or plugins that I should use?

Thanks in advance for your help.